# Trying to disable an input file type button

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to disable an input file type using javascript, but I dont get to disable it. Is it possible? You can check the code here, in this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zdxLg/). Is there another way to disable it? Help please.

JAVASCRIPT

```
  document.getElementById('upload').disable=true;
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a missing "d".

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. It should be `disabled`, not `disable`:

```
document.getElementById('upload').disabled=true;
```

[Fixed JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zdxLg/1/)